# SSRS Display Aggregate Value of Child level group to Parent level group

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, reporting

[Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23JMC.png)

I am trying to get the sum of all the status, which is a child group called "Status1" to Parent group called Assignee.

I have created a report variable called Val and used in a custom code below

```
function addData(val as Double, 
                 val1 as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable
                )
   val1.value = val1.value + val
   return val
end function
```

The calculation is working as desired. The sum  of all statuses at the last column in the picture has the correct value of 135 at the last row.

I want the sum 135 be shown in Assignee level group.I called the Report Variable like this  =Variables!val1.Value on that text field, however, the value is 0.0 instead of 135.

it seems like Global Report variable again got flushed, when we try to access it at assignee level group parent group.

Can someone please help me on how to get 135 in Assignee level ? I would appreciate your assistance. I have been struggle to understand the scoping of those child level group to Parent level group relationship.

Comment: Have you tried just `return val1.value + val` instead of setting the variable value?

Comment: Thank you StevenWhite for such a quick response. If you click on Calculate link on the very top of the request, you will see the visual of my problem.

 If you look at the 2nd last column, It has  124 , it is calculated as
=Code.addData(sum(CountDistinct(Fields!Incident_number.Value))/Countdistinct(Fields!Priority.Value),Variables!val1)

Comment: Have you tried `=sum(CountDistinct(Fields!Incident_number.Value‌​))/CountDistinct(Fie‌​lds!Priority.Value) + ​Variables!val1.Value`

Comment: Thank you StevenWhite for such a quick response. If you click on Calculate link on the very top of the request, you will see the visual of my problem.

 If you look at the 2nd last column, It has  124, 9, 1, 1, it is calculated as
=Code.addData(sum(CountDistinct(Fields!Incident_number.Value))/Countdistinct(Fields!Priority.Value),Variables!val1)

I wanted to hold the sum of those values. Then use it anywhere in report. Last column with Value 124, 133, 134, 135 I have called it as =Variables!val1.Value, and it is showing up perfectly fine as calculation is correct. but 0.0 at top level

Comment: Thanks Steve
that will be 311+53+8+9+1+1 = 383/3 = 127.67 that is not what I want. I want 124 + 9 + 1 +1 = 135

Comment: Did anybody have any suggestion !!!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a combination of the Status and the Incident Numbers. You can get the distinct count at that level by combining the two like this:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!Status.Value + CStr(Fields!Incident_number.Value‌​))
```

Comment: that returned 383 rather than 135

Comment: What is the expression currently in the box with the 124 value?

Comment: =Code.addData(sum(CountDistinct(Fields!Incident_number.Value))/Countdistinct(Fields!Priority.Value),Variables!val1)
Please look at the Calculate link for the structure of the report. Thank you very much for looking it Steve

Comment: OK, sorry, that is too complicated to do in the report. I would suggest writing a subquery to get the additional calculations at that level.

Comment: thanks Steve as you suggested used subquery instead to solve this issue. At least now I know there is some limitation in Report when comes a scoping and a hierarchical grouping